# MDX How to dynamically name a member

Tags: mdx, iccube-reporting

In the following MDX, I want to name my calculated member  "Evolution 2012-2015" if the parameter @{AnneeSelected} is equal to "2015"

```
with CALCULATED MEMBER [Periode].[Periode].[Evolution] AS percChange(@{AnneeSelected}, @{AnneeSelected}.lag(2) ) 
SET [Years with data] AS  @{AnneeSelected}.lag(2):@{AnneeSelected} 
select {[Years with data]} + {[Periode].[Periode].[Evolution]} on 0,
{[Measures].[NbSejours], [Measures].[Séjours Théoriques], [Measures].[Séjours Réels], [Measures].[Nombre Lits], [Measures].[Population]}  ON 1
 FROM [Cube]
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change its name but you can define the CAPTION property.

```
with member xx as 42, CAPTION = "Marc"
select xx on 0 from [Sales]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Seems that caption accepts only "hardcoded" string...    Not something like `with member xx as  [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2015].name, caption = memberToStr( [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2015].name)
select 
xx  on 0 from [Cube]`

Comment: Yes the CAPTION must be a string. But it seems that in your initial example CAPTION is based on @{AnneeSelected} which is something handled in the reporting application (javascript). This event should be replaced in the client side before the query is sent to the server.